# Looping through a repeater control to delete all files where a checkbok is checked in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asprepeater

I am creating a dropbox application where I would like the use to be able to check all the checkboxes next to the file name and the do a multiple delete. For flexibility with the design, I have the files and checkboxes printed on the page using an ASP.net repeater rather than gridview.

See below my current code which I have made using similar examples on the internet. The main issue I'm having is I'm unsure who to get the loop to pick up on whether the checkbox is checked for each unique repeater item.

.aspx code

```
 <asp:Button  ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn-uploader "OnClick="ButtonDelete_Click" Text="Delete" />

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate> 
          <!-- Drag and Drop Uploader --> 
          
          <!-- Carry on -->
          <div id="rptCard" class="card card-style fileItemMainBorder" >
            <div class="content fileItemMainBorder2" style="display: flex;">
              <p class="font-50 pt-3 dragtext" style="float: left;">
                <input id="checkboxes" class="file-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                <span style="font-size: 1em; color: #ff6a00;"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i></span>&nbsp; <a href="exampleModalLabel<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="fileItemMain" data-bs-target="#exampleModal<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName").ToString().Replace("%20", " ")%></a> </p>
              <div class="pe-3 pt-3" style="margin-left: auto;"><a href="Content/Files/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserID")%>/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Filename").ToString().Replace("%20", " ")%>"><img src="img/icons/icon_download.png" class="iconhover me-3" style="width: auto; height: 20px;" alt="Download"></a> 
                  
              <a href="deleteLabel<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#delete<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>"><img src="img/icons/icon_delete.png" class="iconhover" style="width: auto; height: 20px;" alt="Delete"></a> </div>
            </div>
            <!-- document viewer -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header"> <span class="close ms-3" data-bs-dismiss="modal">&times;</span> </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <embed src="Content/Files/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserID")%>/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Filename").ToString().Replace("%20", " ")%>" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"> 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end modal --> 
            <!-- modal-2 -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="delete<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteLabel<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Please confirm you want to delete this file.</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body justify-content-center text-center">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete:<br />
                    <h5><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName").ToString().Replace("%20", " ")%></h5>
                    </p>
                    <p class="font-12" style="color:red">This action will delete this file and CANNOT be undone.</p>
                  </div>
                  <a href="file-delete.aspx?fid=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileID")%>" style="float:right; display: inline;" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Yes, I understand, proceed with file delete</a> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end modal-2 --> 
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

VBScript Code

```
 Protected Sub ButtonDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Connect to your database (e.g., using SqlConnection)
        Dim sSqlConnectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ToString

        Dim uid As Integer
        Try
            uid = Session("sessUID")
        Catch ex As Exception
            uid = 0
        End Try


        ' Get the list of files and checkboxes from the form

        Dim checkboxes As String() = Request.Form.GetValues("checkboxes") ' Assuming 'checkboxes' is an array of checkbox values

        ' Loop through the files and checkboxes
        For i As Integer = 0 To getFileName().Length - 1
            If checkboxes(i) = "on" Then ' Assuming the checkbox value is "on" when checked
                ' Delete the file
                Dim filePath As String = "C:\Liaison\training.liaisonsystems.com\Content\Files\" & uid & "\" & getFileName() 'Adjust the path As needed
                If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath)
                End If

                ' Delete the record from the database
                Dim sDeleteSQL As String = "DELETE FROM Files WHERE FileID = @FileID"
                Dim SqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(sSqlConnectionString)
                Dim SqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sDeleteSQL, SqlConn)
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileID", getFileName())
                SqlConn.Open()
                SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                SqlConn.Close()

            End If
        Next

        ' Redirect back to the original page or display a success message
        Response.Redirect("file-uploader.aspx")

    End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop in a asp.net check box, no need to use a HTML one. (not particular clear why you did???).

So, say this markup:

```
<div style="width: 16%">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <h3>Select Hotels</h3>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="DataPK" runat="server"
                Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

            <asp:Label ID="lblHotel" runat="server" Width="250px"
                Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>'>
            </asp:Label>

            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSEL" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <hr style="background-color: black; height: 1px" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>

<br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdShowSel" runat="server" Text="Process Selected"
    OnClick="cmdShowSel_Click"
    CssClass="btn" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblSel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

And code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If
End Sub


Sub LoadData()

    Dim rstData As DataTable =
        MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
               ORDER BY HotelName")

    Repeater1.DataSource = rstData
    Repeater1.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdShowSel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strSelectedPK As String = ""
    For Each rRow As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items

        ' get check box, and database PK id
        Dim chkSel As CheckBox = rRow.FindControl("chkSEL")
        Dim hPKID As HiddenField = rRow.FindControl("DataPK")

        If chkSel.Checked Then

            If strSelectedPK <> "" Then strSelectedPK &= ","

            strSelectedPK &= hPKID.Value
        End If

    Next


    ' now delete rows selected

    Dim strSQL =
        $"DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID IN ({strSelectedPK})"

    '  MyExecute(strSQL)

    lblSel.Text = $"PK id list selected = {strSelectedPK} <br/>
                  SQL to execute <br/>{strSQL}"


End Sub
```

And result is now this:

[image]

Of course in above I used 2 helper routines, since typing "over and over" code to setup a connection string and to execute SQL is something one will do over and over. So, in my module of helper routines, I have these 2 helper routines.

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

Public Sub MyExecute(strSQL As String)

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

## Edit: SQL injection safe example.

```
Protected Sub cmdShowSel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strSelectedPK As String = ""
    Dim sParms As String = ""
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand()
    For Each rRow As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items

        ' get check box, and database PK id
        Dim chkSel As CheckBox = rRow.FindControl("chkSEL")
        Dim hPKID As HiddenField = rRow.FindControl("DataPK")

        If chkSel.Checked Then

            If strSelectedPK <> "" Then strSelectedPK &= ","
            strSelectedPK &= hPKID.Value

            If sParms <> "" Then sParms &= ","
            Dim sP As String = $"@p{rRow.ItemIndex}"
            sParms &= sP
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(sP, SqlDbType.Int).Value = hPKID.Value
        End If

    Next

    ' now delete rows selected
    cmdSQL.CommandText = $"DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID IN ({sParms})"

    Dim strSQL As String =
        $"DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID IN ({strSelectedPK})" ' for display only

    'MyRstPE(cmdSQL)

    lblSel.Text = $"PK id list selected = {strSelectedPK} <br/>
                  SQL to execute <br/>{strSQL}"

End Sub
```

And my helper routine:

```
Public Sub MyRstPE(cmdSQL As SqlCommand)


    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And with all of the "ui" update code removed, then we get this:

```
Protected Sub cmdShowSel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim sParms As String = ""
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand()
    For Each rRow As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items

        ' get check box, and database PK id
        Dim chkSel As CheckBox = rRow.FindControl("chkSEL")
        Dim hPKID As HiddenField = rRow.FindControl("DataPK")

        If chkSel.Checked Then
            If sParms <> "" Then sParms &= ","
            Dim sP As String = $"@p{rRow.ItemIndex}"
            sParms &= sP
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(sP, SqlDbType.Int).Value = hPKID.Value
        End If

    Next

    ' now delete rows selected
    cmdSQL.CommandText = $"DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID IN ({sParms})"

    MyRstPE(cmdSQL)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yikes. This will create an SQL injection vulnerability in the code. Scary stuff here.

Comment: No, it does not! We are not putting user input into the sql string. We using a hidden field with viewstate. If a user were to hit f12 (browser tools) and modify the value of the viewstate, you would get a page post error. I 100% agree that one should NEVER take ANY user input from a text box etc. for use in sql. However, we not doing that in this example. To be fair, I would have used a list view, since then we can use datakeys, and use 100% server side and NEVER expose the PK id to the client side browser. In fact, as a general rule, I NEVER expose database PK id's to the client side browser.

Comment: There are tools that make it trivial to spoof anything you want into viewstate and still pass the checks. Regardless, a `MyExecute()` method that only accepts an SQL string, without a separate mechanism for query parameters, **IS** going to be abused in extremely unsafe ways.

Comment: It is not all that easy. Viewstate can be spoofed, but it going to be difficult.

Comment: However, in the interest of the group, I do  agree, and will update my code to use parameter's

Comment: See the updated code (it also a great example of how to add multiple parameter's, since many often don't realize that you can independent add parameter's without  SQL having been set or even created.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Checked if you modify a hidden field with F12. I  CONFIRM  NO viewstate protection. Hitting f12 and modify values in markup and on post-back, the modified PK value was used. In effect, the first part of my code can NOT be used, and it is NOT injection safe, and it NOT even safe from a simple f12 and modifying the DOM. No special tools are required. This means that first code snip of mine CAN NOT be used, and I stand 100% corrected. Appreciate those coming back to un-down-vote due to my corrected code. My point that viewstate protection exists here? Nope, and I am 100% wrong